# How can I explicitly set directionality of bidirectional text so it displays properly when two conflicting languages are used together?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, localization, bidirectional

I'm trying to implement localization and the directionality of the content gets thrown off when I try to display the mixed characters on the page.

I'm using a json file which holds all of the text content, and that is being inserted into the dom using a Vue.js template.

The characters display correctly until there is a mixture of RTL and LTR text in the same string.  At that point, the text does not display correctly.

What works:   [ENGLISH ENGLISH ENGLISH]
Also works:    [ARABIC ARABIC ARABIC]

What fails:   [Arabic Arabic English Arabic]

The directionality of the entire file is set to "rtl" on the main HTML element, and the language="ar".

What can I use in terms of unicode characters or some other code that will allow me to section off the English word in a sentence that is surrounded by arabic text and maintain the directionality of the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HTML `dir` attribute not only on the document itself, but also on elements. So you can wrap any english text inside an RTL text in a span alement for example and set the attribute `dir="ltr"`. Alternatively, you can achieve the same via CSS using `direction: ltr;` in conjunction with `unicode-bidi: bidi-override;`.

You could also use the `<bdi>` tag, but it's currently not well supported (only Firefox and Chrome so far).

Yet another approach, whithout using any surrounding HTML element, would be to insert a non-printable `left-to-right marker` via the `&lrm;` entity after any punctuation mark, but that doesn't seem very feasible.

```css
html {
  direction: rtl;
}

.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<h3>via the <code>dir</code> attribute</h3>
لكن لا بد أن <span dir="ltr">Lorem Ipsum!</span>&rlm;أوضح لك أن كل
<h3>via CSS</h3>
لكن لا بد أن <span class="ltr">Lorem Ipsum!</span>&rlm;أوضح لك أن كل
<h3>Using the <code>&lt;bdi&gt;</code> tag</h3>
لكن لا بد أن <bdi>Lorem Ipsum!</bdi> أوضح لك أن كل
<h3>Using <code>&amp;lrm;&lrm;</code></h3>
لكن لا بد أن Lorem Ipsum!&lrm; أوضح لك أن كل
```

Comment: This is great.  It helps me out with my problem.